# Curl returns true instead of value

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a simple API. However, not sure why but I'm getting true instead of the value that should be returned.

Here's the curl code.

```
try
        {
        $target_url = "my url";
        $post = array(
            'auth_token' => '123456' // post your auth token here
            //'file_contents' => '@' . $_FILES['file']['temp_name']); //the name of the input type is file, you can change it in your HTML.
            );
        $ch = curl_init();
        if($ch == false)
        {
            echo "Couldnt initialize curl";
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        $result=curl_exec ($ch);
        if (FALSE === $result)
            throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
        var_dump($result);
        curl_close ($ch);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);
        }
```

The file which gets the content :-

```
return $_POST['auth_token']
```

However, the result of *var_dump* is bool(true) instead of 123456.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to `echo` not `return`:

```
echo $_POST['auth_token'];
```

And you need `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to have `curl_exec()` return the content:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

[curl_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the
>   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on
>   success, FALSE on failure.

Comment: Hi @AbraCadaver
That worked for me. How can I return a text file ? (Like I echo'ed auth token here)

Comment: The text file will return as text since the server will send it as text.

Comment: So echo "somefile.text" will return the text of it?

Comment: Just `curl_exec()` the location of the text file.

Answer (score 0):

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
you need to put that to return data in proper format also you can check datatype of your output using gettype($string);