# How can I handle data returned from an API endpoint (django application) in a php laravel application route

Tags: php, python, laravel, django-rest-framework

I have a Django API application using Django rest framework which works just fine. I have another PHP laravel application that is supposed to consume the API. When I post data to the API endpoint using curl, the data is stored and an object is returned.

I am supposed to grab this object and use the data. However, the object that is returned is printed on the page when I visit the route that executes the post request.

When I do `dd($data)` with the variable that is supposed to contain the returned data, I get a boolean (true when the data was posted successfully and false if something went wrong).

```
Route::get('test-create-client', function (){
    try {
        $data = ApiController::createClient('John D', '0711111111', '', 'Male', '1980'.'-'.date('m-d'));

    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        return $exception->getMessage();
    }
    dd($data); // I get a boolean from here
 });
```

//creatClient from the ApiController

```
public static function createClient($name, $phone, $care_of, $gender, $date_of_birth)
{
    $url = "client/clients/";
    $client = '{
                "name": "'.$name.'",
                "telephone_number": "'.$phone.'",
                "alternative_telephone_number": "'.$alt_phone.'",
                "care_of": "'.$care_of.'",
                "gender": "'.$gender.'",
                "date_of_birth": "'.$date_of_birth.'",

            }';
    return ServicesApiController::RunCurlPostServices($url, $client);
}
```

//CurlRequest

```
    public static function RunCurlPostServices($url, $json)
{
    $ch = curl_init(env('SERVICES_API_URL').$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type:   application/json",
        "authorization: token *******"));
    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

I need `$data` to have the data returned by the API endpoint and not a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

In order for curlpost to return the content returned by an API request, I had to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true. For some reason I had missed it out.

So updating my curl request to

```
public static function RunCurlPostServices($url, $json)
{
    $ch = curl_init(env('SERVICES_API_URL').$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                        "Content-Type:   application/json",
                        "authorization: token *******"));
    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Fixed the issue. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995172/curl-returns-true-instead-of-value) helped.
Thanks for the effort @Rezrazi

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not have a built in http client, for that you need to use a tool or a package.

I recommend [guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) and its [documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/)

You can use it this way in your **GET** method

```php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://myapplication.com/endpoint');
$data = $res->getBody();
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am executing the API call using curl in the ApiController. The request is executed properly. The issue I have is that the data returned prints its self on the route that executes. What I want is the data to be contained in the variable ```$data``` and not just a boolean.

Comment: You should check the return from your method on the `ApiController`. Your question does not provide any details about the behavior of the `createClient` method

Comment: I have updated the question to include the ApiController method as well as the curl request being executed. Thank you.